# Algebraic structure satisfying interchange law

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, binary-operations

Is there a name for an algebraic structure that satisfies a rule equivalent to the interchange law from category theory? Say, a set $A$ with associative (not necessarily commutative) operations $\cdot$ and $\circ$ such that for $a, b, c, d \in A$,
$$ (a \circ b) \cdot (c \circ d) = (a \cdot c) \circ (b \cdot d).$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [duoid](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/duoidal+category#bimonoids_bicomonoids_and_duoids) comprises a pair of monoids structures $(A, \circ)$ and $(A, \cdot)$ on the same set satisfying the interchange law $(a \circ b) \cdot (c \circ d) = (a \cdot c) \circ (b \cdot d)$. For instance, see (2.4) in Garner–Franco's [Commutativity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.08710) for a definition valid in any [duoidal category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/duoidal+category).